# Can Postgres do this? (Specifically without a function() construct)?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql, plsql

I have some oracle calls that I am porting.  Today I came across this code which looks like "procedural" language, but is not declared in a function or anything... My question is:  Can postgres handle this in this form?  What form does this need to be in?

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
   IF :start_time IS NULL OR
      :start_date IS NULL OR
      :end_time IS NULL OR
      :end_date IS NULL  THEN
         INSERT INTO ARPSPACE_AVAILABILITY
            (ARP_ARPSPACE_NM, ASA_TIME_ID, ASA_START_DT, ASA_END_DT)
         SELECT :arpspace_name,
                 1,
                 ASP.ASP_START_DT,
                 ASP.ASP_STOP_DT
           FROM ASP 
          WHERE EXISTS
             (SELECT ARP.ARP_ARPSPACE_NM
                FROM ARPSPACE ARP
               WHERE ARP.ARP_ARPSPACE_NM = :arpspace_name);
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not yet without declaring a function. In version 9.0 (soon in Beta) this will be possible: http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/sql-do.html

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, *if* you can declare a function. See [plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpgsql.html) from the manual for details.

Comment: Not yet possible, you have to wait for 9.0

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this (assuming :*labels* are prepared query parameters)?

```
     INSERT INTO ARPSPACE_AVAILABILITY
        (ARP_ARPSPACE_NM, ASA_TIME_ID, ASA_START_DT, ASA_END_DT)
     SELECT :arpspace_name,
             1,
             ASP.ASP_START_DT,
             ASP.ASP_STOP_DT
       FROM ASP 
      WHERE EXISTS
         (SELECT ARP.ARP_ARPSPACE_NM
            FROM ARPSPACE ARP
           WHERE ARP.ARP_ARPSPACE_NM = :arpspace_name)
      AND  (:start_time IS NULL OR
            :start_date IS NULL OR
            :end_time IS NULL OR
            :end_date IS NULL);
```